# Apache jena ARQ FILTER optimization

Tags: sparql, jena, arq

I have a reasonable implementation of Jena over MongoDB by providing impls for `Graph` and `DatasetGraph`.  SPARQL queries are converted into the appropriate query expressions in MongoDB and material, at least on triple-match-by-triple-match basis, is vended in a high performance way.  This is not a surprise; indexes do what they're supposed to do.  `Graph` is wrapped with an RDFS reasoner `Model` and all is fine.

I am interested in now exploring ways to optimize filtering push-down into MongoDB.  For example, this SPARQL:

```
?s a:attested "2017-06-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime .
```

results in this setup of a MongoDB `find` expression:

```
{ "P" : "a:attested", "O" : { "$date" : 1496275200000 } }
```

And all is good.   But this SPARQL:

```
?s a:attested ?theDate .
FILTER (?theDate = "2017-06-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime)
```

causes ARQ to pass only the predicate to `Graph::find()`:

```
{ "P" : "a:attested" }
```

and a whole lot of things are pulled from the DB and the filtering is done in ARQ itself.  The `FILTER` expression above is obviously not needed for a simple equality but it proves the point.

The [TDB documentation says](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/architecture.html) that "... TDB uses the `OpExecutor` extension point of ARQ."   But the link for `OpExecutor` [goes to a To-Do](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/TODO).

Can anyone point at any examples of anything where something can be hooked or otherwise accessed around the time ARQ calls `Graph::ExtendedIterator<Triple> find(Triple m)`?  It is at this point that my implementation jumps in to craft the query, and if I can ask if filters exist, then I can "improve" the restriction on the query.   At this time, it is not so important that I deal with stopping the filtering from happening **again** in ARQ itself.

Comment: I guess you already had a look [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/arq-query-eval.html) and [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/algebra.html). Anyways, please ask this on the Jena mailing list, the community is fast htere

Comment: @AKSW  Well, the OpEx stuff yes, and "reverse engineering" sdb/store/LibSDB.java and sdb/engine/QueryEngineSDB.java.   Not for beginners for sure...

Comment: You wil need to provide an OpExecutor for your system.  By only implementing Graph/DatasetGraph, there isn' access to filters, and it's left to the general purpsoe executor. All it can do is pull data from the graph and filter it.

Comment: I came across a project called HDT which is a dictionaried/compressed rep for big triple set.  They have a graph AND query Plan/OpEx plugin for Jena; it is a well coded and relatively compact implementation so you can actually get a sense of what's going on.  https://github.com/rdfhdt/hdt-java